# /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found

Tags: c, embedded, beagleboneblack

I am trying to compile a program to put on a BeagleBone black, but im getting this error
when running the program on my board:

```
/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found
```

I made sure that i cross compiled for ARM (arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc).

On my desktop, I have EGLIBC 2.17-9.
What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had face the same problem.
Solved it by the following steps.

1. Downloaded "libc6_2.17-0ubuntu5.1_i386.deb"
2. sudo dpkg -i ipts libc6_2.17-0ubuntu5.1_i386.deb

`sudo dpkg -i ipts libc6_2.17-0ubuntu5.1_i386.deb`

Comment: Care to provide a link to said file?

Answer (score 6):

Download 64 bit package from this site https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/amd64/libc6/2.17-0ubuntu4

Install libc6 2.17 by the command ,

sudo dpkg -i libc6_2.17-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb

Cheers !

Answer (score 2):

You don't have glibc 2.17 installed on your target board.  You need to ensure that you have the SAME version of glibc (for ARM) installed on both the target board and on your build machine (your desktop).  You can do this by either installing 2.17 on the target board or by figuring out what version you have installed there and installing that same version on your build machine (and linking with it).

Answer (score 1):

This shell script worked for me: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/beagleboard/oPq-Xt0TVdY

see the response from "A P" which is a script that installs a later version on the beaglebone black:

I am running a beaglebone black rev C with debian wheezy.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian sid main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update
apt-get -t sid install libc6 libc6-dev libc6-dbg
echo "Please remember to hash out sid main from your sources list. /etc/apt/sources.list"
```